# Bootstrap menu change li active class on click

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following menu by bootstrap

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active" id="homeL"><a data-scroll href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="" id="workL"><a data-scroll href="#Work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

how can I alter changing the `<li>` class to active when either home or work is clicked?

The following isn't working for me

```
$("#homeL").on("click",function(){
  $(".nav navbar-nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Your css selectors seems to be wrong. Please try as given below,

```
<script>
    $(".nav li").on("click", function() {
      $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });

</script>
```

I have created a plunkr for this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4qhuzgnCXUm86rCoUPii)

Comment: Please look at my updated answer. I created a plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/4qhuzgnCXUm86rCoUPii . Isn't this what you are after?

Comment: thank for your help however it is still not working out for some reason. check it out on my website www.ericbartolo.com and you can inspect element. Thanks

Comment: Ok never mind, I followed your plunkr and it is working now, I was missing the function, how reckless of me. Thanks a lot @THara

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("ul li").on("click", function() {
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

You will have to play around with it with your given tags. What helped me was declaring *this* to become active, then removing the active class.

Answer (score 2):

one of your selectors is malformed, by looking at your html it looks like on the third line of the script that selector isn't doing what I think you want it to.

```
$("#homeL, #workL").click(function(){

  //$(".nav navbar-nav li") <-this is looking for a <li> inside a <navbar-nav>  
  // tag inside a tag with the class "nav"

  $(".nav.navbar-nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".ul li").on("click", function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

This is the solution that worked for me. I declared this to become active and remove the active class and also adding the .siblings() method that allows you to search for the siblings of the li elements in the document.

Comment: For this: $(.ul li) I think you mean this:$(ul li) - assuming ul is an element not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Include this script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.nav a').filter(function(){
            return this.href==location.href}).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        $('.nav a').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')    
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found another workaround for this which is very easy to use.

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="<?php if($page=="home.html"){echo "active";} ?>"> id="homeL"><a data-scroll href="home.html">Home</a></li>
       <li class="<?php if($page=="about.html"){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
       <li class="<?php if($page=="work.html"){echo "active";} ?>"> id="workL"><a data-scroll href="work.html">Work</a></li>
       <li class="<?php if($page=="contact.html"){echo "active";} ?>"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```