# Add 'active' class to same href as current clicked sidebar menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

How would one add active class to tab and remove it from all other with click on the same href link click in the dropdown menu?

```
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar py-3">
 <ul class="sidebar-menu list-unstyled">

   <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="/test" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted active"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Dashboard</span></a>
   </li>

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="/test2" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Test</span></a>
   </li>
<ul>

</div>

<style>
.sidebar-link.active, .sidebar-link:focus {
    background: #e2e8ed;
    color:grey !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for a click on an `<a>` element, and then remove all classes and add a class to the clicked element:

```js
$("a").on("click", function() {
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sidebar-link.active,
.sidebar-link:focus {
  background: #e2e8ed;
  color: grey !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar py-3">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu list-unstyled">

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted active"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Dashboard</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Test</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem @JesusSarmiento, always glad to help.

Comment: my friend what happens if i using laravel and on click the item is refresh ,  and the item is not selected ('not active')

Answer (score 0):

You can check this or refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518099/bootstrap-menu-change-li-active-class-on-click)

```js
    $("ul> li").on("click", function() {
      $("ul> li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

```css
.sidebar-link.active, .sidebar-link:focus {
    background: #e2e8ed;
    color:grey !important;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar py-3">
 <ul class="sidebar-menu list-unstyled">

   <li class="sidebar-list-item active"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted "><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Dashboard</span></a>
   </li>

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Test</span></a>
   </li>
<ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```js
const $sidebarA = $('#sidebar a');
$sidebarA.on('click', () => $sidebarA.toggleClass('active'));
```

```css
.sidebar-link.active,
.sidebar-link:focus {
  background: #e2e8ed;
  color: grey !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar py-3">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu list-unstyled">

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted active"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Dashboard</span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="sidebar-list-item"><a href="#" class="sidebar-link text- 
   muted"><i class="la la-dashboard mr-3 text-gray "></i> 
   <span>Test</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```